# SSAS adding a custom attribute member to a cube for reporting

Tags: ssas, bids

We have a cube with many measures and one of the main dimensions is a 'site' dimension with about a dozen sites.

I've been asked to add a 'site' that is basically ALL the sites.

They don't want the actual hierarchy,

I tried defining the ALLMEMBER attribute but they don't want another hierarchy level, they want an actual attribute member at the same level. They want the whole displayed as another site next to the actual site values

Example:

Right now with the all member attribute I can show

```
All Sites - 140
  +
    New York   45
    Chicago    60
    Boston     35
```

But what they want is this:

```
New York   45
Chicago    60
Boston     35
All Sites  140
```

I'm not sure where to go from here in BIDS.  It's not really a named dataset, nor a calculated measure.  It's really a custom attribute member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a calculated Dimension member in your cube calculation script.

You'd need something like:
Create member Site.site.AllSiteCalc AS SUM(Site.site.children,Measures.currentmember)

Once you've processed the cube this should become available in ssms,excel or to use in a query

Comment: I've never done this before, just to be clear:  Do I enter this in the calculations tab in BIDS?  The 'create member' statement I mean...and it will appear under the dimension once it's in?

Comment: Yes,under calculation tab.

Comment: Thank you!  It works!  Now I just have to figure out how to use the proper aggregate for whatever is selected (some are sum, some are average etc....) and I'm good to go!   Thanks again.